Unable to delimit text into columns in R after pdf parsing
I have converted a pdf to text and trying to delimit the text which is not working properly
library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)
library(lubridate)

pdf_rowwise <- strsplit(pdf_text("V://path//sample.pdf"), split = "\n")
pdf_rowwise[[4]][6: length(pdf_rowwise[[4]])]

# txt <- pdf_rowwise[[4]][6: length(pdf_rowwise[[4]])]

output:
 [1] "BarCode                   : 10581274"                                                                                
 [2] ""                                                                                                                    
 [3] "Test Name                                          Result               Biological Ref. Int.            Unit"        
 [4] ""                                                                                                                    
 [5] ""                                                                                                                    
 [6] "                                        Lipid Profile (Heart Risk Profile),Serum"                                    
 [7] "TOTAL CHOLESTEROL SERUM                            229H                 Desirable : Upto 200          mg/dl"         
 [8] "  (Method : CHOD-PAP)"                                                                                               
 [9] "                                                                        Borderline : 200 - 239 High :"               
[10] "                                                                        More than 240"                               
[11] "TRIGLYCERIDES SERUM                                115.3                Normal : Upto 150 Border Line mg/dl"         
[12] "  (Method : GPO )"                                                                                                   
[13] "                                                                        : 150 - 199 High : 200 - 499"                
[14] "                                                                        Very High : > 500"                           
[15] "HIGH DENSITY LIPOPROTEIN CHOLESTEROL               47                   35.3 - 79.5                   mg/dl"         
[16] "  (Method : HDL DIRECT)"                                                                                             
[17] ""                                                                                                                    
[18] "VERY LOW DENSITY LIPOPROTEIN VLDL                  23.06                7 - 30                          mg/dl"       
[19] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[20] ""                                                                                                                    
[21] "LOW DENSITY LIPOPROTEIN                            158.94H              85 - 150                        mg/dl"       
[22] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[23] ""                                                                                                                    
[24] "TOTAL CHOLESTEROL / HDL CHOLESTEROL                4.87                 3.0 - 5.0                       Ratio"       
[25] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[26] ""                                                                                                                    
[27] "LDL / HDL CHOLESTEROL RATIO                        3.38                 2.5 - 3.5                       Ratio"       
[28] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[29] ""                                                                                                                    
[30] "NON- HDL CHOLESTEROL                               182H                 < 160                           mg/dl"       
[31] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[32] ""                                                                                                                    
[33] "TOTAL LIPID                                        550.24               400 - 1000                      mg/dl"       
[34] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[35] ""                                                                                                                    
[36] "                                   Extended Liver Profile (Liver Function Test),Serum"                               
[37] "BILIRUBIN TOTAL                                    0.7                  Upto 2.0                        mg/dL"       
[38] "  (Method : DIAZO)"                                                                                                  
[39] ""                                                                                                                    
[40] "BILIRUBIN DIRECT                                   0.3H                 0.0 - 0.20                      mg/dl"       
[41] "  (Method : DIAZO)"                                                                                                  
[42] ""                                                                                                                    
[43] "BILIRUBIN INDIRECT                                 0.4                  0.00 - 1.00                     mg/dl"       
[44] "  (Method : Calculated)"                                                                                             
[45] ""                                                                                                                    
[46] ""                                                                                                                    
[47] ""                                                                                                                    
[48] ""                                                                                                                    
[49] "                                                                                                        Page 4 of 18"

from Above text I just need [11] "TRIGLYCERIDES SERUM                                115.3                Normal : Upto 150 Border Line mg/dl"  split into 3 columns
As someone suggested in post SO post on parsing I was able to parse this with below code:
pdf_rowwise[[4]][6: length(pdf_rowwise[[4]])] %>%
                strsplit("    +") %>%
                Filter(f = \(x) length(x) == 3)

output:
[[1]]
[1] "TRIGLYCERIDES SERUM"                 "115.3"                              
[3] "Normal : Upto 150 Border Line mg/dl"

its above output that I would like to split into columns of dataframe
Working fine even in below step:
pdf_rowwise[[4]][6: length(pdf_rowwise[[4]])] |>
                strsplit("    +") |>
                Filter(f = \(x) length(x) == 3) |>
                lapply(paste, collapse = "|") |> 
                do.call(what = "c")

output:
[1] "TRIGLYCERIDES SERUM|115.3|Normal : Upto 150 Border Line mg/dl"

Issue: Now when I try to split this into columns based on delimiter then it doesn't work:
pdf_rowwise[[4]][6: length(pdf_rowwise[[4]])] |>
                strsplit("    +") |>
                Filter(f = \(x) length(x) == 3) |>
                lapply(paste, collapse = "|") |> 
                do.call(what = "c") |>
                read.csv(text = _, check.names = FALSE, sep = "|")

output:
0 rows

I have also tried below code using dplyr even that is not working
pdf_rowwise[[4]][6: length(pdf_rowwise[[4]])]  %>% 
                strsplit("    +") %>% 
                Filter(f = \(x) length(x) == 3) %>% 
                lapply(paste, collapse = "|")  %>%  
                do.call(what = "c") %>% 
                data.frame() %>%
                separate_wider_delim(.,delim = "|",
                                     names = c("Test Name","Result","Unit"))

output:
Error in `separate_wider_delim()`:
! `cols` is absent but must be supplied.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% ...
 2. tidyr::separate_wider_delim(., delim = "|", names = c("Test Name", "Result", "Unit"))


If txt is the character vector with 49 elements shown in the question then use txt |> strsplit("    +") |> lengths() to investigate the lengths.

yes I was able to identify length of 3 and wanted to split a 2 piped text into 3 columns and it wasnt working well. But now it worked with this code %>% as.tibble() %>% separate_wider_delim(value, delim = "|",names = c("Test Name","Result","Unit"))
